# Mtls token request failed with error - AuthenticationScheme: x509 was forbidden

Tags: identityserver4

I am trying to use Identityserver4's new Mutual TLS client authentication. I have followed the documents in the `Identityserver4` web site ([Mutual TLS](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/mtls.html)).

When I tried to a get a access token for mtls client, I get error "Forbidden". When I inspected the `IdentityServer4` log file:

```
2019-06-11 10:19:26.690 +00:00 [INF] Request finished in 23.3151ms 200 application/json; charset=UTF-8
2019-06-11 10:19:26.784 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://open-banking-authorisation-server-host/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks  
2019-06-11 10:19:26.786 +00:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
2019-06-11 10:19:26.816 +00:00 [INF] Request finished in 32.05ms 200 application/jwk-set+json; charset=UTF-8
2019-06-11 10:20:41.797 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://open-banking-authorisation-server-host/connect/mtls/token application/x-www-form-urlencoded 80
2019-06-11 10:20:41.814 +00:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: x509 was forbidden.
```

Could anyone help please?

```
var clientId = "adsjasdjakafklfalvf";
FileStream f = new FileStream("client_cert.crt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
int size = (int)f.Length;
byte[] data = new byte[size];
size = f.Read(data, 0, size);
f.Close();

var cert = new X509Certificate2(data);

var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

var newClient = new HttpClient(handler);

var tokenResponse = await newClient.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
{
    Address = $"{_authorityBaseUri}/connect/mtls/token",

    ClientId = clientId,
    Scope = "accounts"
});

var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;

newClient.Dispose();
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

you should

1. Enable SSL in IS4.
2. Create client certificate.
3. Enable IIS Express to accept client certificate.

   Client App

```cs
static async Task<TokenResponse> RequestTokenAsync2()
{
    var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler();
    var cert = new X509Certificate2("mtls.test-client.p12", "changeit");
    handler.SslOptions.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection { cert };

    var client = new HttpClient(handler);

    var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:44302");
    if (disco.IsError) throw new Exception(disco.Error);

    var response = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = disco                              
                .TryGetValue(OidcConstants.Discovery.MtlsEndpointAliases)
                .Value<string>(OidcConstants.Discovery.TokenEndpoint)
                .ToString(),

                ClientId = "mtls",
                Scope = "api1"
        });

    if (response.IsError) throw new Exception(response.Error);
    return response;
}
```

IS4

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCertificate(options =>
            {
                options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
                options.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
            })

    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.MutualTls.Enabled = true;
            options.MutualTls.ClientCertificateAuthenticationScheme = "Certificate";
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        })
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
        .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users);
    builder.AddMutualTlsSecretValidators();
    builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    //app.useh
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    });
}
```

Further reading:

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/mtls.html#

https://leastprivilege.com/2020/02/07/mutual-tls-and-proof-of-possession-access-tokens-part-1-setup/

https://improveandrepeat.com/2017/07/how-to-configure-iis-express-to-accept-ssl-client-certificates/

https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET/Using-mkcert-for-ASPNET-Core-Development